# Bootstrap Carousel make shake my content when small screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have develop responsive website using bootstrap in new version. I use carousel to all screen. But when small screen (I have try on my phone), the carousel will shake my content. That mean, after slide 1 => 2, all my content will be shake but when use desktop device its normally. This my code:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item"><img src="img1.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img2.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img3.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 4000
    });
  });
</script>
```

last: Css

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
html,
body,
.carousel,
.carousel-inner,
.carousel-inner .item {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top:0px;
}
```